# Octokit.dll Как загрузить/удалить файл в свою репозиторию на GitHub

Tags: c#

Нужно сначала удалить файл (Find.cs) и затем загрузить обновлённый этот же файл (Find.cs) с моего компьютера на мой аккаунт в указанный репозиторий, но у меня появляется ошибка

```html
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using Octokit;

    public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task UploadAsync()
    {
var client = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue("GitHub"));
var basicAuth = new Credentials("name", "password");
client.Credentials = basicAuth;
var tokenAuth = new Credentials("token ");
client.Credentials = tokenAuth;

using (var archiveContents = File.OpenRead(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "/Find.cs"))
{
       var assetUpload = new ReleaseAssetUpload()
       {
            FileName = "Find.cs",
            ContentType = "name/repositories",
            RawData = archiveContents
       ;
       var release = await client.Repository.Release.Get("name", "repositories", 1);
            var asset = await client.Repository.Release.UploadAsset(release, assetUpload);
    }
```

Ошибка: Не удается преобразовать из "System.Threading.Tasks.Task" в "Octokit.Release"

Comment: У вас Release.Get() является асинхронной задачей, которую вы вызываете как обычный метод. Используйте async/await, либо делайте костыли, написав в конце .Result (не советую так делать!!)

Comment: Создал метод и написал весь этот код в него (public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task UploadAsync()). Ошибка всё ещё осталась

Comment: Я не вижу, чтоб вы использовали await.

Comment: Всё, ошибка исчезла. Сейчас исправлю на готовое решение код. Если не сложно, посмотрите, правильно или нет

Comment: Да, все верно. Только не исправляйте вопрос на правильный, сделайте ответ.

Comment: Только проблема, как его сейчас вызвать в основном методе Main? Как обычно, UploadAsync() не получается, тк "Поскольку этот вызов не ожидается, выполнение текущего метода продолжается до завершения вызова"

Comment: Как и любой другой асинхронный метод, внутри async метода/задачи. В недавних версиях с# можно Main метод переделать в static async Task Main(string[] args) {} и вот вам уже одно из решений.

Comment: Но, если я переделаю Main под async, то программа не будет содержать статического метода Main

Comment: Пробовал сейчас оставить метод void у Main и изменить вызов async таким образом: var task = UploadAsync(); task.Wait();, но программа вылетает вообще на этапе вызова этого метода

Comment: Почему не будет? Если у вас не используется какой нить древний .Net и и древний C#, то все там будет работать. Вот [документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-1#async-main). Раньше многие использовали такую конструкцию `static void Main() => new Program().Run().GerAwaiter().GetResult();`, где `Run` - `async Task Run()` с нужной задачей. Также можете сделать `static async void Method()` и его вызвать в `Main`, но учтите, что `void` не дожидаются.

Comment: Спасибо. Конечно, сейчас мне метод, который на GitHub загружает файл - он возвращает Not found, но, думаю, с этим дальше как-нибудь сам разберусь, наверное